# Mongoose - update after populate (Cast Exception)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am not able to update my mongoose schema because of a CastERror, which makes sence, but I dont know how to solve it.

Trip Schema:

```
var TripSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    _users: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});
```

User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
});
```

in my html page i render a trip with the possibility to add new users to this trip, I retrieve the data by calling the findById method on the Schema:

```
exports.readById = function (request, result) {
    Trip.findById(request.params.tripId).populate('_users').exec(function (error, trip) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error getting trips');
        } else {
            console.log('found single trip: ' + trip);
            result.json(trip);
        }
    })
};
```

this works find. In my ui i can add new users to the trip, here is the code:

```
var user = new UserService();
user.email = $scope.newMail;
user.$save(function(response){   
    trip._users.push(user._id);
    trip.$update(function (response) {
        console.log('OK - user ' + user.email + ' was linked to trip ' + trip.name);

        // call for the updated document in database
        this.readOne();
    })
};
```

The  Problem is that when I update my Schema the existing users in trip are populated, means stored as objects not id on the trip, the new user is stored as ObjectId in trip.
How can I make sure the populated users go back to ObjectId before I update? otherwise the update will fail with a CastError.

[see here for error](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s117/sh/68de812b-9ade-4441-b4f3-749d40a74459/497be23f8efa259896e1b17caee55e2f/deep/0/update%20trip%20-%20CastError.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching around for a graceful way to handle this without finding a satisfactory solution, or at least one I feel confident is what the mongoosejs folks had in mind when using populate.  Nonetheless, here's the route I took:

First, I tried to separate adding to the list from saving. So in your example, move `trip._users.push(user._id);` out of the $save function. I put actions like this on the client side of things, since I want the UI to show the changes before I persist them.

Second, when adding the user, I kept working with the populated model -- that is, I don't `push(user._id)` but instead add the full user: `push(user)`.  This keeps the _users list consistent, since the ids of other users have already been replaced with their corresponding objects during population.

So now you should be working with a consistent list of populated users. In the server code, just before calling $update, I replace trip._users with a list of ObjectIds.  In other words, "un-populate" _users:

```
user_ids = []
for (var i in trip._users){
    /* it might be a good idea to do more validation here if you like, to make
     * sure you don't have any naked userIds in this array already, as you would
     */in your original code.
    user_ids.push(trip._users[i]._id);
}
trip._users = user_ids;
trip.$update(....
```

As I read through your example code again, it looks like the user you are adding to the trip might be a new user?  I'm not sure if that's just a relic of your simplification for question purposes, but if not, you'll need to save the user first so mongo can assign an ObjectId before you can save the trip.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts! i still cant beliefe that there is a nicer solution for that! in my real life app i have the code for adding new user to trip on the server (i personally update the client when server returns successfully). i guess the idea of working with user object instead of id should work for me too. yes it is a new user but i will add the user to trip only after 'user.$save' returns successfully.

Comment: This question is the only place on the internet I could find something relevant to my problems. Unfortunately this is the same way I'm handling things now but using underscorejs makes it a little nicer `user_ids = _.pluck(trip.users, "_id")`, though not much. But this problem is seriously making me consider a db rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an function which accepts an array, and in callback returns with an array of ObjectId. To do it asynchronously in NodeJS, I am using async.js. The function is like:

```
let converter = function(array, callback) {
  let idArray;
  async.each(array, function(item, itemCallback) {
    idArray.push(item._id);
    itemCallback();
  }, function(err) {
    callback(idArray);
  })
};
```

This works totally fine with me, and I hope should work with you as well